# Error deploying existing App Service using Pulumi.Azure

Tags: azure, pulumi

I'm getting `2020-10-29T22:27:58.8724283Z I1029 22:27:58.870264    4596 eventsink.go:78] eventSink::Infoerr(<{%reset%}>panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not map[string]interface {} 2020-10-29T22:27:58.8728827Z <{%reset%}>) 2020-10-29T22:27:58.8735984Z I1029 22:27:58.870264    4596 eventsink.go:78] eventSink::Infoerr(<{%reset%}>goroutine 199 [running]: 2020-10-29T22:27:58.8767921Z <{%reset%}>) 2020-10-29T22:27:58.8778359Z I1029 22:27:58.870264    4596 eventsink.go:78] eventSink::Infoerr(<{%reset%}>github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/azurerm/internal/services/web.expandAppServiceLogs(0x47f6180, 0xc0013eca00, 0x4, 0x47f6180, 0xc0013eca00, 0x1)` when I try to deploy an existing App Service to Azure.

This error prevents my stack to be deployed to Azure.

```
   var webApi = new AppService(appServiceName, new AppServiceArgs
                {
                    Name = appServiceName,
                    ResourceGroupName = resourceGroupName,
                    Identity = new AppServiceIdentityArgs {Type = "SystemAssigned"},
                    AppServicePlanId = appServicePlanId,
                    AppSettings =
                    {
                        {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE", webApiCodeBlob},
                        {"AzureStorage__AccountName", storageAccountName},
                        {"AzureStorage__AccountKey", storageAccountPrimaryAccessKey},
                        {"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY", appInsightsInstrumentationKey},
                        {
                            "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING", appInsightsConnectionString
                        },
                        {"ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION", "~2"}
                    },
                    ConnectionStrings =
                    {
                        new AppServiceConnectionStringArgs
                        {
                            Name = "AzureServiceBusConnectionString",
                            Value = serviceBusConnectionString,
                            Type = "Custom"
                        },
                        new AppServiceConnectionStringArgs
                        {
                            Name = "BlobStorageConnectionString",
                            Value = blobConnectionString,
                            Type = "Custom"
                        },
                        new AppServiceConnectionStringArgs
                        {
                            Name = "MongoConnectionString",
                            Value = cosmosAccountConnectionString,
                            Type = "Custom"
                        }
                    },
                    SiteConfig = new AppServiceSiteConfigArgs
                    {
                        AlwaysOn = true,
                        Cors = new AppServiceSiteConfigCorsArgs
                        {
                            AllowedOrigins = allowedOrigins
                        }
                    },
                    Tags = new InputMap<string>()
                    {
                        {"team", Team},
                        {"product", Product},
                        {"productId", ProductId},
                        {"environment", environment},
                        {"service", ServiceName}
                    },
                });
```

If the App Service does not exist it works the first time. This only fails when it is deploying an existing App Service. This only happens when there is no Logs section defined in the App Service.

I'm using Pulumi 3.28.0

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to solve this issue, it is based on this https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure/issues/383#issuecomment-549192628

It looks like when there is no Logs section configure in the App Service and it tries to translate your C# stack into Pulumi's internal representation there is a nil value that can't be mapped, open the link to see more accurate details about the root cause of this.

Here is how I was able to make it work.

Add the Logs section to your AppService

```
 Logs = new AppServiceLogsArgs
                    {
                        ApplicationLogs = new AppServiceLogsApplicationLogsArgs
                        {
                            AzureBlobStorage = new AppServiceLogsApplicationLogsAzureBlobStorageArgs
                            {
                                Level = "Information",
                                RetentionInDays = 1,
                                SasUrl = $"${storageAccount.PrimaryBlobEndpoint}{blobSas}"
                            }
                        },
                        HttpLogs = new AppServiceLogsHttpLogsArgs
                        {
                            FileSystem = new AppServiceLogsHttpLogsFileSystemArgs
                            {
                                RetentionInDays = 1,
                                RetentionInMb = 100
                            }
                        }
                    },
```